# Trouble with Arrays in Java and for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I keep getting an error but Im not understanding why. The error is about not being able to convert from double to int but I have everything declared in double so I dont understand why im getting this error.

```
class ConeArray{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] coneArray; 

        for(double i = 0; i < coneArray.length; i++) {
            coneArray = Math.PI * Math.pow((i*2),2) * (1/3 * (4 * i));

            System.out.println("Volume of cone: " + coneArray[i]);
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `double i` in your for loop. Array indexes must be ints.

Also, I don't see you actually instantiating the array in the code sample you provided. The current implementation will throw a NPE if you try to access it.

Comment: I thought it can be any type of value like char, string, int, float etc.

Comment: The array elements can be of any types. The array indices, however, are only ints.

Comment: ok so i changed the for loop to int i but now it giving me an error on the multiplation saying double cant be double[]

Comment: You are trying to assign your multiplication result - a `double`, to the `coneArray` variable, that is of type `double[]`. You can't do that. If you want to assign the multiplication result to the array element at position `i`, you should use `coneArray[i] = <multiplication>`

Comment: keep getting that error

Comment: At least update your code on the question. The error message is pretty explanatory, just take a better look at the code and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: `(1/3 * (4 * i));` This will always be zero regardless of the value of i.